# How to select files with certain Labels in a Matlab Project?

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab project with many files. I'd like to get a list of the files having a particular Label (CategoryName:Name). I'm thinking some sort of query like `select f from p.Files where f.Labels ...`.

```
% Load project
p = matlab.project.loadProject('.');

% Print files part
p.Files   

ans = 

  1x970 ProjectFile array with properties:

    Path
    Labels
    Revision
    SourceControlStatus

% Print entries for a file
% Notice it has a Label
p.Files(3)

ans = 

  ProjectFile with properties:

                   Path: "..."
                 Labels: [1x1 matlab.project.Label]
               Revision: ""
    SourceControlStatus: Unmodified

% Print file label
% Classification:Design should be in my list
p.Files(3).Labels

ans = 

  Label with properties:

            File: "..."
        DataType: 'none'
            Data: []
            Name: "Design"
    CategoryName: "Classification"

% Print label of a test file
% Classification:Test should NOT be in my list
p.Files(4).Labels

ans = 

  Label with properties:

            File: "..."
        DataType: 'none'
            Data: []
            Name: "Test"
    CategoryName: "Classification"
```

Any neat way of doing it? (Struggling with `arrayfun` and so far it's not working nor neat.)

Comment: The obvious first step would be to write a simple `for` loop over `p.Files(idx).Labels.Name` which you can then check for a condition. Before [optimising too early](https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451) I'd start out with making sure the code actually runs and does what it should do.

Comment: @Adriaan Yeah, it crossed my mind for-looping it. Reluctant because it either meant copying the control flow all over the place, or making many shallow or overly complex functions.

Answer (score 2):

Think I got it:

```
% Make array of the labels
% Note: 99% of execution time is spent here (Matlab R2019b)
labels = [p.Files.Labels];

% Select labels matching the condition
testLabels = labels(([labels.Name] == "Test") & ([labels.CategoryName] == "Classification"));

% Make array of the test label file components
testFiles = [testLabels.File];
```

I think this is about as terse as it gets. Performance is good enough so I'll think no more of it, but please add a comment if you see something obvious that may be of interest for someone else.

Comment: Not clear to me why you'd need an `arrayfun` to do two simple comparison operators, should be possible to make this a vectorised op, i.e. `testLabels = labels( (labels.Name == "Test") & (labels.Category == "Classification") )`. Note I've omitted some square brackets around the `labels.___` categorical arrays too, not got a project to test with but just syntactically these look surplus to requirements. Note it becomes a single ampersand (`&`) for a vector op where you had a double ampersand (`&&`) for a scalar op

Comment: @Wolfie Nice catch, arrayfun is indeed not necessary! Though I need to wrap `labels.(Name|Category)` in `[]`. Guessing it's somehow related to the `matlab.project.Label` type.